# Ayuda con método en php y tabla recursiva utilizando symfony

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony2

Quisiera por favor me ayuden con un método que debo hacer utilizando lenguaje PHP y el patrón MVC.

Quiero mostrar en mi `Form` una lista `ComboBox` que tengo en una tabla recursiva llamada catálogo de mi BD, el método que contiene la sentencia SQL de mi `Entity` y que quiero poner en mi `Controller` es la siguiente:

```
public function getCatalogoQueryBuilder($catalogo_id, $activo=true) {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cat')
                        ->select('cat')
                        ->Where('cat.catalogo_id=:catalogo_id');
        if($activo){
            $qb->andWhere('cat.activo=:activo')
            ->setParameter('activo', true);
        }

        $qb ->setParameter('catalogo_id', $catalogo_id)
            ->orderBy('cat.orden,cat.nombre', 'ASC');

            return $qb;

    }
}
```

Vuelvo a reiterar que este método utiliza recursividad y es por eso que no he podido sacarlo.

Comment: Recursividad por qué, es una relación 1-M con la misma tabla catalogo ???